# Is there any possibility to have a sliderInput for hours which can select a range from 22 to 3am?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to have a sliderInput for hours (0:00 to 23:59) which can select a range from 22pm to 4 am. Currently this is not possible as the range is always between min (0:00 ) to max(23:59)

```
           sliderInput("timeRange", "Filter inputs by time",   
                        min = as.POSIXct("2017-01-01 00:00:00"),   
                        max = as.POSIXct("2017-01-01 23:50:00"),   
                        value = c(as.POSIXct("2017-01-01 00:00:00"),  as.POSIXct("2017-01-01 23:50:00")) ,
                        timeFormat="%H:%M",
                        #ticks = FALSE,
                        step = 600
            )
```

I would like to have the possibility to select a range for example from 22 to 3 am

Answer (score 1):

I would present the user two days to make this possible

```
           sliderInput("timeRange", "Filter inputs by time",   
                        min = as.POSIXct("2017-01-01 00:00:00"),   
                        max = as.POSIXct("2017-01-02 23:59:00"),   
                        value = c(as.POSIXct("2017-01-01 23:00:00"),  as.POSIXct("2017-01-02 02:00:00")) ,
                        timeFormat="%H:%M",
                        #ticks = FALSE,
                        step = 600
            )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this approach does not work if you wanna filter the data afterwards like this:
`time2 >= format(input$timeRange[1], "%H%:%M:%S",tz = "CET") & time2 < format(input$timeRange[2], "%H%:%M:%S",tz = "CET") `

Comment: You will need to find another way to apply your filter. I would test 2 conditions `time2` on `2017-01-01` and `time2` on `2017-01-02` to account for all possibilities.